# What's the most Pythonic way to make all 2-way comparisons in a sequence?

Tags: python

What's the most Pythonic way to make all 2-way comparisons in a sequence?

**What I've tried so far:**

```
[compare(i, j) for i in sequence for j in sequence]
```

Horrible. Does n^2 instead of n/2(n-1) comparisons. Also compares an item to itself.

```
l = []
for i in xrange(1,len(sequence)):
    for j in xrange(i-1):
        l.append(compare(sequence[i], sequence[j]))
```

Ugly.

```
[compare(i, j) for i, j in permuations(sequence, 2)]
```

This could be it, but not sure if it's Pythonic.

Comment: `permutations()` gives you all possible orderings, so n^2-1 results. If order is irrelevant, try `combinations()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a variation of one of your examples (nested *for* loop, running time: *(n - 1) n / 2*) using [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
seq = (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64)

def compare(a, b):
    print('%s ~ %s' % (a, b))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i, item in enumerate(seq, start=1):
        for other in seq[i:]:
            compare(item, other)
```

Which outputs:

```
1 ~ 2
1 ~ 4
1 ~ 8
1 ~ 16
1 ~ 32
1 ~ 64
2 ~ 4
2 ~ 8
2 ~ 16
2 ~ 32
2 ~ 64
4 ~ 8
4 ~ 16
4 ~ 32
4 ~ 64
8 ~ 16
8 ~ 32
8 ~ 64
16 ~ 32
16 ~ 64
32 ~ 64
```

---

With [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), it can be written even shorter:

```
import itertools

# ...

for a, b in itertools.combinations(seq, 2):
    compare(a, b)
```

Comment: @miku: Good call, I switched between two way and one way matches in my examples. combinations, not permutations.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
[compare(seq[k], i) for k in range(len(seq)) for i in seq[k+1:]]
```

This follows the same comparison pattern as your 2nd snippet.